# Getting exception with library-release.aar file with ibm-watson speech to text

Tags: android, ibm-watson

I am getting this issue with IBM-Watson Speech to text java sdk, Its working fine when I am using a library project source code given with it, while it gives the following error when using library project library-release.aar file.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3 Process: com.book.reading, PID: 12353
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
> Lcom/sun/jna/Library; at
> com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.MicrophoneCaptureThread.run(MicrophoneCaptureThread.java:72)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.sun.jna.Library" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/com.book.reading-dHpwYZuOlQuiIAAnLaOW-Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.book.reading-dHpwYZuOlQuiIAAnLaOW-Q==/lib/arm64,
> /data/app/com.book.reading-dHpwYZuOlQuiIAAnLaOW-Q==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
> /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]] at
> dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) at
> com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.MicrophoneCaptureThread.run(MicrophoneCaptureThread.java:72)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting **transitive:true**?

```
dependencies {
   compile(name:'library-release', ext:'aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

> Some direct dependencies may have dependencies of their own. These are
> called transitive dependencies. Rather than requiring you to manually
> declare each transitive dependency, Gradle automatically gathers and
> adds them for you.